# Auto-reconnect in autobahn python

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn, wamp-protocol

In autobahn python, it seems like if my initial connection failed there's no way to tell, or any callbacks that I can override in my `WampClientProtocol` subclass. I tried overriding `clientConnectionFailed`, but it didn't get called when the connection failed.

The only output I get when the connection failed is

```
2013-09-29 22:17:50-0500 [Uninitialized] Stopping factory <autobahn.wamp.WampClientFactory instance at 0x20ee758>
2013-09-29 22:17:50-0500 [Uninitialized] WebSocketClientFactory stopped
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is not AutobahnPython specific - the [Twisted way of handling this](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html#auto4) is overriding `clientConnectionFailed` (the initial connection already failed .. "host unreachable" and such) and/or `clientConnectionLost` (there once was a connection that got lost .. or closed regularily).

Comment: Ah, I tried overriding `clientConnectionFailed` on my Protocol class, not my Factory class. Thanks for the help!